# Django - can't load javascript files into templates

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I`ve tried several combinations of settings but cannot get my javascript files to load in my templates. When I try to debug my code in Pycharm, it gives an error saying it's trying to find my static files in my "templates" folder.'

from settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = ('django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
                   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")),

STATIC_ROOT = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static"))
```

Project/templates/index.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   <title>React Flux</title>
   <script src="{% static 'js/fb.me/react-0.13.3.js'%}"></script>
   <script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script
</head>
   <body>
       <div id="component"></div>

   <script type="text/jsx">
       var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
         render: function() {
           return <div>Hello World!!</div>;
         }
       });

       React.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('component'));

   </script>
```

My error:

GET http://localhost:63342/Project/templates/%7B%%20static%20'js/fb.me/react-0.13.3.js'%%7D 404 (Not Found)

What´s causing this error?
Why is it looking for my static file in the templates folder?

EDIT:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'^$', 'Core.views.home' , name='home'),)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: You don't appear to be accessing this template through Django at all: the template tags are not being parsed, and the port is suspicious. Exactly what URL are you using?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman 
Excuse my ignorance - I´m completely new to frontend development. I´m using the built-in development server on port 8000. Do the 2 ports have to match? 

Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
"GET /static/js/fb.me/react-0.13.3.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1786

Comment: I don't understand. That's a completely different log entry to the one you showed above.

Comment: The log I just posted is feedback from the terminal. The first one I posted is when I debug index.html in Pycharm

Comment: Well, I don't know what "debugging in Pycharm" involves but it is clearly the wrong thing to do, as it is bypassing Django entirely. So don't do that, we should concentrate on the actual problem shown in the terminal. Do you actually have that path inside the `static` directory?

Comment: My static directory is:
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")),

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93199/discussion-between-frank-and-daniel-roseman).